# Running ipython script using a new extenction

Tags: ipython, transformer-model

I am writing an IPython extension that defines a new shell transformer (see http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.core.prefilter.html#IPython.core.prefilter.PrefilterManager), and I need to use this extension (and syntax defined by the shell transformer) in a script.  However, a simple test reveals that the standard IPython `%run` commands does not work as expected: when the commands in the script are pasted directly in the IPython prompt, everything is fine; if instead I run the IPython script with

`%run script.ipy`

the new syntax is not recognized (i.e., it looks like the new shell transformer is not used).